Stimulus Issues in Rails 7.1.3
I have created a new rails app from scratch with

Ruby 3.3.3
Rails 7.1.3

1 Stimulus controller works without any problem.
However when I add second controller nothing seems to work.
I am getting
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Controller' has already been declared
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '.default' has already been declared
I checked at the compiled JS, the issue is that import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus' andexport default ... is defined twice in the application.js (probably because of adding this in 2 differents controller.
This is my code for importmap.rb
pin 'application'
pin '@hotwired/turbo-rails', to: 'turbo.min.js'
pin '@hotwired/stimulus', to: 'stimulus.min.js'
pin '@hotwired/stimulus-loading', to: 'stimulus-loading.js'
pin 'bootstrap', to: 'bootstrap.min.js', preload: true
pin '@popperjs/core', to: 'popper.js', preload: true
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/controllers', under: 'controllers'


Code for controllers/index.js
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
const application = Application.start()
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus   = application
import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
eagerLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)

Code for application.js
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .

import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"

Code for 2 controllers with different file name.
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  ...
}

I tried adding import .. in index.js and remove default from export line and giving each class a name.
It than throws other issues and none seems to work.
I want that my controllers works seamlessly without me registering each controller manually.
Any help is appreciated.
